# Start/Stop VMs v2 - how to enable for VMSS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I have found this Azure function which can start and stop VMs based on a schedule or the actual CPU load.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview

This is working fine for my single VMs but the main point why I wanted to have this is for our Virtual Machine Scale Set VMs.

In the Azure function I have included the RG where the VMs and the VMSS are deployed. But when I run the function it will only affect the single VMs.
I also tried to enter the VMSS via the VMLists attribute, but that did not work either.

Is there a specific way how I can include the VMSS VMs to also be part of the Azure function or can they not be implemented into this?
And if not what can I use to manage this VMSS so that I can define an automatic start and shutdown?

Comment: Aren't you looking for the built-in autoscale mechanism https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview ? There you can scale up/down based on CPU load but also doing on a scheduled basis.

Comment: No, I am trying to reduce the costs for our devlopment environment that is not actively being used during the night or on weekends. Therefor I want to shutdown the VMSS instances during that time and restart them on e.g. monday morning.
The VMSS is attached to a ServiceFabric which requires a minimum of 3 VMs (I am not allowed to scale to 0). I have tried (by hand) to shut them down and afterwards to restart them again and this worked. After the shutdown I saw that they are stopped and deallocated so that I don't have to pay for them. But I wanted to automate this.